# Connecting to lines, which are not spatially connected to each other, using FME?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, line

I have a shapefile, which contains lines. These lines are not spatially connected to each other.

More specifically the end of one linestring has a slightly different coordinate from the start of the next linestring (5th or 6th decimal digit).

Is there a way to connect these lines together using FME 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Snapper transformer, with End Point Snapping and a tolerance of 6.

Comment: Why tolerance of 6?

Comment: You said in your question that there is a distance of 5 or 6 decimal degrees between the end points.

Comment: Ah I see. I meanth there is a difference on the 5 or 6th decimal digit of the coordinates. The unit of my coordinate system is in meter so I it works fine for me with tolerance 1 meter.

Answer (score 0):

The non-automatical way would be to use the **snapping** function.

So select the feature and then drag the specific point of it to another with active **snapping** for sure. After that select both features and use the ***Merge Selected Features*** option. Now you should have one feature at the end.

If this is not a solution for your please describe the issue a bit more in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking for an automated solution using one transformer from FME. I am not sure if something like this is provided though. I have hundreds of linestrings and it wouldn't be possible to do this manually!